# Force relative div to be on top of absolute div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page where I'm integrating some JS code for onclick ads.

It is that annoying popup ad that pops up when you click anywhere in the page.

The JS code is obfuscated but I can see that it creates a div with absolute position and z-index 2000 to be on top of all elements .

I'd like to make a specific div on top of this overlay so that when I click on it the overlay div don't capture the click, So I made the specific div position relative with higher z-index 3000. but still when I click on it the ad is opened

```
<div id="connectedObjects" style="position:relative;height:200px;width:200px;background-color:red;z-index:5000">
```

Example:-
http://jsfiddle.net/egjzxdjs/

Is there a way to force a specific div over the overlaying div ?

Comment: I think jsfiddle is blocking your javascript from running, because I don't see any ads and only 1 div is being rendered. That being said, if you are just trying to make it so that the ads aren't clickable, then you can set `pointer-events: none;` in your css on the ad itself.

Comment: It is working in jsfiddle but you might not be targeted. There is no div for the ad. it is a popup ad when you click anywhere in the page. I just want to make an exception for a specific div by giving it higher z-index placing it on top of the ad assuming that this way when I click on this div the ad won't popup

Comment: It won't matter how high your z-index is if the ad pops up no matter where on the page you click.

Comment: As you can see in this example http://jsfiddle.net/HUGNd/ when The div with the higher Z-Index is clicked the event doesn't propagate to the lower div. That is exactly what I want to do however it is not working in the fiddle I attached. May be the ad JS code is doing some sneaky thing to capture the event.